# Google Cloud: Wordpress Site Doesn't Link to Custom Domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, google-app-engine

On Google Cloud I installed Wordpress. Then I setup a custom domain. My host has linked my domain name to Google cloud. My problem is when I type my domain name I get this message "requested URL was not found on this server." How do I link my Wordpress site which has an external IP address to my domain name? Google Cloud automatically creates the records and I used that info to have my provider switch my domain to Google. My site has been down for 2 days since switching to the cloud. I so desperately need to get my site up asap.

Comment: Not sure why you tagged this as [[tag:azure]]. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Did you set up custom domain following instructions at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/domain ?

What do you see in the App Engine error log ? (available in the Developer Console)

Answer (score 1):

I see it’s been quite a while since this was asked, but if someone else need this, here’s what you need to do:

Part 1:

1. Go to Networking > Cloud DNS > Create Zone
2. It’ll create 4 NS records. You should update the NS records of your domain with these.
3. Create an A record on Google Cloud DNS Zone and enter IP address of Google Cloud External IP.

Part 2:

1. Go to App Engine > Settings > Custom Domain
2. It’ll give you a TXT-SPF record for you to authenticate domain address, update this too, as you did NS records of your domain.
3. Then select the domain you’ll use
4. Update the A records as you did for NS and TXT-SPF records.

Note: You don’t need to update AAAA records for now, because some providers do not provide IPv6.